# How do you in/outdent a line without selecting it in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Whether the cursor is in front of the text, where Tab and Shift-Tab work, or anywhere else, I mean.  MonoDevelop uses Ctrl+Alt+Home or Ctrl+Alt+End for this functionality, and you can easily find the commands in its Edit->Format menu.

Learning how to operate the keyboard is harder for Visual Studio than any other program I have used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio is very flexible when it comes the the keyboard, even if it's not super friendly.

[image]

1. Go to *Tools -> Options*
2. Type `dent` into the *Show commands containing* text box
3. Find `Edit.DecreaseLineIndent`
4. Focus the *Press shortcut keys* text box
5. Type your preferred keys, eg: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>
6. Check where those keys are currently used. Notice that there are many scopes to which keystrokes apply. You probably want to select *Text Editor* from the *Use new shortcut in* dropdown
7. If you want to apply this shortcut, click *Assign*
8. Do the same for `Edit.IncreaseLineIndent`

It's not a bad idea to make a backup of your settings once you have them the way you like them.

Comment: Thanks!  That menu is horrible.  It would be nice to have documentation linked to what the commands are; I just picked one out of the blue, "tfsreparentbranch", and nothing came up on Google.

Comment: I completely agree. It'd be great to see descriptions of them alongside. I imagine that'd be a lot of work for Microsoft's internationalisation team!